# What is the differences between flow control and access control?

Tags: layer2, layer4, throughput

We first apply access control methods to get access to the channel link followed by the flow control methods to stop the receiver from overflowing.

Suppose we are using CSMA/CD in access control method then it has own throughput, efficiency etc. And in flow control we are using suppose Go-back-n(GBN) mechanism then it has also  own throughput, efficiency etc.

My question is what is the difference between access control throughput, efficiency and flow control throughput, efficiency?

Comment: I don't understand the question. throughput is number of successfully transmitted bytes/sec, efficiency is presumably link utilization which is [time spent on something successfully transmitted]/[total time spent] (usually measured over some repeated interval). You can either measure or model said values for method X. Then you get values for method X. If method X is not the same as method Y, then the values would be different. You can measure a real system, having method X, Y, and Z. They you will get value for a combination X, Y, Z. (you can probably model too, but i never saw this done).

Comment: so, i guess throughput and efficiency of access control and flow control are just different values of the same quantities measured for access control and flow control respectively. Since I only saw these values (or models) in isolation, I would assume that the value of access control does not take flow control into account and vice versa.

Comment: @Effie could you answer this question, I waiting for your answer.I need to understand throughout, efficiency of flow control of laye4, layer2(LLC Sublayer of DLL) and access control efficiency, throughput layer2(Mac Sublayer) ?

Comment: I don't remember how to do it, and I would have to google it as well.

Comment: @Effie could we say access control throughput is less than flow control throughput?  please differentiate access control throughput and flow control throughput? Please reply... I am still waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

(Ethernet) *Flow Control* uses pause frames to slow down a sender when it's sending more data than the receiver can handle. It can cause head-of-line blocking and needs to be used with care (or not at all). Flow Control is used for full-duplex transmission only, half duplex used backpressure (deliberate collision/jam signaling).

*Access control* is a range of protocols that are used to secure access to a physical (switch) port.

CSMA/CD is a largely obsolete *media access control* (MAC) protocol, used to arbitrate a shared (wired) Ethernet medium.

Go-back-n (ARQ) is an *error-control method*. Variants are used by the TCP transport-layer protocol and by the wireless IEEE 802.11 data link layer.

All of those are (almost) entirely different things.

Comment: when we use access control throughput, efficiency means efficiency,throughput of sender Or receiver and flow control (suppose stop and wait)throughput, efficiency means throughput, efficiency of physical link?

Comment: They have very little to do with each other.

Comment: @RonTrunk don't understand, please elaborate more.

Comment: Throughput and efficiency have no meaning for access control.

Comment: @RonTrunk but I read in book aloha, slotted aloha, csma access control they have efficiency, throughput?

Comment: the term may be used in different contexts.  But flow control and MAC are two different things

Comment: @RonTrunk so what is the difference between access control throughput and flow control throughput?

Comment: I think the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ALOHAnet#ALOHA_protocol) explains it better than I can

Comment: @RonTrunk before posting question read it, but I can't differentiate between access control throughput and flow control throughput? As per my understanding when we use access control throughput, efficiency means efficiency,throughput of sender Or receiver and flow control (suppose stop and wait)throughput, efficiency means throughput, efficiency of physical link?Am I correct?

Comment: @RonTrunk flow control uses network throughput which is the rate of successful message delivery over a communication channel. The data these messages belong to may be delivered over a physical or logical link, or it can pass through a certain network node.    And access control throughput is system throughput or aggregate throughput is the sum of the data rates that are delivered to all terminals in a network? Am I correct?

Comment: @Zac67 first access control is happened or first flow control?

Comment: @AlokMaity *Media* access control is physical layer/L1, so it's "first". Flow Control is over data link layer/L2.

Comment: @Zac67 so what is the difference between access control throughput and flow control throughput? Please tell ... I am still waiting for your reply.

Comment: "{Flow|media access} control throughput" is not a thing. Both methods have an impact on potential throughput but the amount very much depends on the scenario.

Comment: @Zac67 could we say layer4 throughput and layer2 throughput and layer1 throughput, all are different things?

Comment: @AlokMaity Yes, we could. Going up in the layers, effective throughput is diminshed by increasing overhead in the lower layers. Potentially, congestion and data loss due to transmission/checksum failures may also eat into the throughput.

Comment: @Zac67 could you insert your above comments in answer...

Comment: You can find the basics in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_flow_control or in IEEE 802.3 Annex 31B, much better than I could explain.

Comment: @Zac67 understood. Ethernet uses flow control layer2 or layer4 or both?

Comment: Ethernet implements layers 1 and 2. Layer 4 belongs to something else, usually TCP/IP. TCP implements its own flow control, many L4 protocols don't (e.g. UDP).

Comment: @Zac67 could we say access control throughput is less than flow control throughput?  Please reply.. I am still very eager to understand.

Comment: See above: *"{Flow|media access} control throughput" is not a thing.* - so you can't say that one is less or more than the other.

Comment: @Zac67 so what is the actual difference between flow and access control throughput?

Comment: @Zac67 you said layer1 throughput is less than layer2 throughput, so we could say access control throughput is more less than flow control?